# Qt Quick Layout Buttons don't show text when focused

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

When I am using the layouts of Qt it does not show the text of the buttons when the application window is focused. When I focus on a different application, e.g. Qt Creator, the buttons show the text. I am on Mac OS Ventura with Qt 6.5.2

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Busy Indicator Control")

    RowLayout {
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
            Button {
                id: button1
                text: "Running"
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                onClicked: {
                    console.log("button pressed")
                }
            }
            Button {
                id: button2
                text: "Not Running"
                Layout.fillWidth: true
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: Focused on the Application]
[image: Focused on Qt Creator]

I tried to use a lower version of Qt, 6.4.3, I also tried to create a new project with the same code and the same result.

Comment: I figured out that this may have to do with the system preferences. My System is in dark mode. When I put it in light mode I can still read the text when it is focused on the application.

Comment: As mentioned before, when switching to light mode, the text can be read normally. My current workaround is to add `QQuickStyle::setStyle("Fusion");` to my main.cpp file.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. If your system is in dark mode, and your Qt app is switching to dark mode for the buttonText, it should also switch to dark mode for the rest of your app, which it clearly is not doing. So, as a workaround, you can force your button text color to lock onto a specific unchanging color, e.g. `Button { palette.buttonText: "black" }`

Answer (score 0):

The reason maybe is system preferences on your macOS.

For workaround, just add the [palette](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-item.html#palette-prop) property to your buttons

```
Button {
    id: button1

    Layout.fillWidth: true
    
    palette {
        buttonText: "maroon"
        button: "lavender"
    }
    
    text: "Running"
    onClicked: {
        console.log("button pressed");
    }
}
```

Or, you can add `QQuickStyle::setStyle("Material");` to your **main.cpp** file.

*Note: You need to add line `QT += quickcontrols2` to the qmake file (.pro) before import QQuickStyle*

```cpp
//main.cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQuickStyle>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickStyle::setStyle("Material");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));

    return app.exec();
}
```

For more information, you can check [Styling Qt Quick Controls](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquickcontrols-styles.html#using-styles-in-qt-quick-controls), [QQuickStyle Class](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qquickstyle.html), and [Qt Quick Controls Configuration File](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquickcontrols-configuration.html).

Answer (score 0):

I used a different workaround. Since I am using Qt6 I do not use qmake anymore. You can add a specific ID for your QtQuick app to your CMake file just like this:

```
# Qt for iOS sets MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER automatically since Qt 6.1.
# If you are developing for iOS or macOS you should consider setting an
# explicit, fixed bundle identifier manually though.
set_target_properties(example_name PROPERTIES
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER com.example.example_name
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)
```

This cmake sniped is the default, you just have to uncomment the 5th line. Once you have that set you can add that Identifier to a be
[excluded from darkmode](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338044/can-i-turn-to-dark-mode-only-for-specific-apps-in-macos-mojave).

If you follow a tutorial or do create a lot of projects for some other reason, just use the same identifier for every project, that way, you do not have to add each and every project to the excluded list.